# Wait at a current position in code till specified condition is met in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, es6-promise

I have this file upload method

```
 async upload(files){
 this.fileuploaded=true;
 for(let i=0 ; i < files.length ;i++){ 
        await new Promise((f) => setTimeout(f, 1500)); 
        this.uploadUrl = await this.uploadServerFile(files[i]);
...
...
}
```

In upload server File method

```
uploadServerFile()
{
..
..
this.fileuploaded=false;
}
```

Is there any way i can wait at the top of this function till  previous files are uploaded

```
 async upload(files){
```

and `this.fileuploaded` is false.

Any solution Please. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to upload them one by one, or all of them at once?

Comment: first you can use promise all if you want to upload multi files together and when all finished you can change the boolean. or if you want to upload 1 by 1 just set the boolean after the for loop (and add a check if all files succeeded)

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu suppose user has selected multiple files it is being uploading and again user selects some files after previous files are uploaded then only the control should move to next step. `this.fileuploaded` this variable will be false when file is uploaded